# UIView resize to fit labels inside of it

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout, resize, constraints

I have a UIView that I'm appending into a stack view on my main page of my app

This is the class of my view:

```
class MyCustomView: UIView {
    public let leftLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    public let rightLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(leftLabel)
        addSubview(rightLabel)

        leftLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        rightLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            leftLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.4),
            leftLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            leftLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            leftLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),

            rightLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6),
            rightLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            rightLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            rightLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        ])
        leftLabel.text = "Short string"
        rightLabel.text = "Short string too"
    }
}
```

And I append to my main stack view with:
`let myCustomView = MyCustomView(frame: .zero)`
`stackView.addArrangedSubview(myCustomView)`

This loads in my label's correctly and resizes everything as I'd want.

However, in my main class, I am updating `myCustomView.rightLabel.text = <New Way Longer Text That Takes 2 Lines Instead of One>`

The text is updating properly, but my `myCustomView` size is not resizing, so part of the text is just being cut-off

I have tried following other answers on here, but none of them seem to work for me.

Am I missing something small in order to force the resize of the customView to fit the label inside of it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not show that you set the `.numberOfLines` in the label(s) to `0` to allow for multi-line labels.

Adding only that, should allow your labels to grow in height and to expand your custom view. However... that will also make both labels expand to the size of the tallest label, resulting in the text of the "shorter" label being vertically centered (I added background colors to make it easy to see the frames / bounds of the views):

[image]

If you constrain the Bottom of your custom view to the Bottom of each label at `greaterThanOrEqualTo` you can keep the labels "top-aligned":

[image]

You can run this code directly in a Playground page to see the results:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyCustomView: UIView {
    public let leftLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    public let rightLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(leftLabel)
        addSubview(rightLabel)

        // background colors so we can see the view frames
        backgroundColor = .cyan

        leftLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        rightLabel.backgroundColor = .green

        // we want multi-line labels
        leftLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        rightLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        // use auto-layout
        leftLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        rightLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain to top
            leftLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            // constrain to left
            leftLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            // constrain width = 40%
            leftLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.4),

            // constrain to top
            rightLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            // constrain to right
            rightLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            // constrain width = 60%
            rightLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6),

            // constrain bottom of view (self) to >= 0 from bottom of leftLabel
            bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: leftLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            // constrain bottom of view (self) to >= 0 from bottom of rightLabel
            bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: rightLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])

        leftLabel.text = "Short string"
        rightLabel.text = "Short string too"
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    var theButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        return b
    }()

    var theStackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.spacing = 8
        v.distribution = .equalSpacing
        return v
    }()

    var myView = MyCustomView()

    // on button tap, change the text in the label(s)
    @objc func didTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        myView.leftLabel.text = "Short string with\nA\nB\nC\nD\nE"
        myView.rightLabel.text = "Short string too\nA\nB"
    }

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        self.view = view

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(theButton)
        // constrain button to Top: 32 and centerX
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 32.0),
            theButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])

        view.addSubview(theStackView)

        // constrain stack view to Top: 100 and Leading/Trailing" 0
        // no Bottom or Height constraint
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100.0),
            theStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])

        theStackView.addArrangedSubview(myView)

        // add an action for the button tap
        theButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```